# Email sent via sendmail showing wrong 'from' address when sent via text message

Tags: python, email, sms, sendmail

I have a cronjob that runs a python script to periodically send an email with status updates to me. On the weekend I prefer this to work via text, so I send it to myphonenumber@vtext.com. This works fine, except the 'from' address is incorrect when it goes to the phone. It shows correctly when it is sent to a regular email address. For some reason when it goes through a text it shows the 'from' address as "myusername@servername.wndowsdomain.local". This may simply be a verizon text message thing specifically, but if possible I'd like to figure out how to fix it as I hope to add some reply functionality to this tool.

The machine that the script is on is running Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is the simple python function I have that sends the email:

```
def sendMail(to,text):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Weekend Report"
    msg['From'] = 'servername@mydomain.com'
    msg['To'] = to
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text,'plain'))
    p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(msg.as_string())
```

Would I be better off using something like smtplib and a gmail account or something perhaps?

Comment: Looks like IPv6 related. Just a hint/guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Sendmail: Setting envelope sender

You may try to set "envelope sender" address **too** (sender address used in SMTP session).

```
p=Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail","-t","-i","-fservername@mydomain.com"],stdin=PIPE)
```

*Comment:* I have added missing `-i` command line option unrelated to setting envelope sender.